# How can I add 'on pageload' to this code?

Tags: javascript

I have a fixed nav bar script which works fine when I'm scrolling, but if I reload the page, the fixed nav is not activated until I scroll again. I need to have it activated when it's not on top. How can I add a 'on pageload' code to this without having it always activated? Something like 'when scrolled 1px away from top then activate'?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {     
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 0) {
        $("#top").addClass("scroll");
        $(".nav li a").addClass("scroll");
        $(".logo").addClass("scroll");
        $(".menu").addClass("scroll");
    }
    else {
        $("#top").removeClass("scroll");
        $(".nav li a").removeClass("scroll");
        $(".logo").removeClass("scroll");
        $(".menu").removeClass("scroll");
    }
});
```

Comment: You should use window.pageYOffset property to check if page is already scrolled. If it's greater than zero, the page is scrolled and then you should make use of it while fixing the nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

just extract that class functionality and execute it again when the page loads?,

(there's room for optimization with the selectors too, you could cache them)

```
function checkScroll() {
 var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
 if (scroll > 0) {
    $("#top").addClass("scroll");
    $(".nav li a").addClass("scroll");
    $(".logo").addClass("scroll");
    $(".menu").addClass("scroll");
  }
  else {
    $("#top").removeClass("scroll");
    $(".nav li a").removeClass("scroll");
    $(".logo").removeClass("scroll");
    $(".menu").removeClass("scroll");
  }
}

$(window).scroll(function() {     
  checkScroll();
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
  checkScroll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function into jQuery to be executed on pageload. `$(function)` You can extract the anonymous callback to a named function and use it for both scenarios.

```
function handleScroll() {     
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 0) {
        $("#top").addClass("scroll");
        $(".nav li a").addClass("scroll");
        $(".logo").addClass("scroll");
        $(".menu").addClass("scroll");
    }
    else {
        $("#top").removeClass("scroll");
        $(".nav li a").removeClass("scroll");
        $(".logo").removeClass("scroll");
        $(".menu").removeClass("scroll");
    }
}

$(handleScroll);
$(window).scroll(handleScroll);
```